# Is there any Wicket-like web framework to use with Scala (besides lift)?

Tags: scala, web-frameworks, tapestry

I want to start a project using the Scala language. While searching for web frameworks I've found Lift. However, it is not what I was looking for: a web framework that has complete separation of HTML and code. Lift does have some nice features (and a learning curve) but we need to have complete separation of HTML and code. I was hoping to find something like Wicket, Tapestry or Barracuda for the Scala language.

Although it is nice to be able to reuse html templates, it is more important to us to have the HTML templates work as a "static  application" mockup. In Tapestry we can just put links in the static templates and use that to have static navigation and a sort of prototype of the application.

So, do you know of any other web framework that is easy to work with the Scala language?

Thanks,
Luis

Answer (score 6):

[Here it is](http://technically.us/code/x/the-escape-hatch) I can understand why you might want it pure Scala, but you haven't stated that's necessary, and with the techniques defined within the blog post, and there is another blog which also helps, you should be able to get it close enough to what you desire.

Answer (score 2):

Tapestry 5 has many similarities with Wicket and works very well with Scala. I haven't tried it myself, but Francois Armand has being doing it for some time and he's writing about in in his [blog](http://fanf42.blogspot.com/search/label/tapestry%205).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Context](http://www.contextfw.net). It is a component based framework written in Java but I have used it with Scala without much difficulties.

Context uses XSL as templating language which forces a sharp separation between logical presentation (DOM-tree) and actual presentation (HTML/CSS/JS).

You can even, with little effort, create prototypes and mocked views by faking the DOM-tree and trying invidual components in different combinations.